# Inserting multiple links into one iframe from txt file, one by one

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put multiple src links into 1 frame, and load them 1 after another. Heres is the code i currently have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#1').on('load', function() {     
            $('#1').attr('src', "http://www.example1.com");             
    }).attr('src', "http://www.example2.lt");

    $('#1').on('load', function() {                 
            $('#1').attr('src', "http://www.example1.com");             
    });

    });
</script>

<iframe id="1"  width="100" height="100" src=""></iframe>
```

In this code it would first load the example1.com url, and then load example2.com url.

I have a txt file that stores urls. How do i make it so javascript would read the urls from txt file, put them in javascript, and load the iframe as many times as there are urls in the txt file, one after another? Maybe there is another method to do so than the one i wrote here?

Comment: But what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: i wanna get loadtimes of each frame, but first i want to load all sources into 1 frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would format the file as `json` encoded array of strings and use `$.ajax` or `$.getJSON` to fetch it from the server.

Now that you have your array set up you can just:

```
$.getJSON( ... , function(success) { 
  $('#1').on('load', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', success.pop());
  }).attr('src', 'http://www.google.com');
});
```

Somewhat like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/FQLce/